# A regex which separate text and text surrounded by html markup

Tags: java, regex

I have that sort of string:

```
 ____<b> <i> Hi</i> </b> my name is <i>Henry</i> and i'm very <span style=\"background-color: rgb(102, 102, 153);\">stylish</span>
```

And I'm searching for a pattern which separate simple text and text with HTML markup, in my exemple I need:

```
____
<b> <i> Hi</i> </b>
 my name is 
<i>Henry</i>
 and i'm very 
<span style=\"background-color: rgb(102, 102, 153);\">stylish</span>
```

I've tried with that pattern:

```
"<[^>]*>][^</]*[\\s]*[<[^>]*>]|[^<[^>]*>][^</]*[\\s]*[^<[^>]*>]"
```

But he only work when there isn't a markup which follow one another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I find the solution:

```
"<[^/]*[^>]*>{1,}[^</]*[\\s]*<[/]{1}[^>]*>{1,}|[^<[^>]*>][^</]*[\\s]*[^<[^>]*>]");
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Clément le BG